# Function1[T, U] => Function1[T, Option[U]]

Tags: scala

How can I take a `Function1[T, U]` and make it a  `Function1[T, Option[U]]`?

Something like:

```
def wrapAsOption[T, U](f: T => U): T => Option[U] = ???
```

It's totally ok to make it always a Some(U).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def optionalize[T, U](f: T => U): T => Option[U] = f.andThen(Option(_))
```

Comment: Worth noting that this will treat nulls differently. `Some` may be preferred in some cases.